# ¿Cómo alinear elementos dentro de una lista a la derecha del contenedor?

Tags: html, css, lista, flexbox

Hola soy nuevo en la programación web, actualmente estoy practicando para mejorar. Me encuentro creando un diseño similar a este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema radica en que no tengo idea de cómo puedo lograr colocar el elemento `<p>$ Price</p>` a la derecha del contenedor, similar a como aparece "$ 120,00" en la primer imagen. He intentado colocar justify-content: space-between pero los elementos permanecen en el mismo lugar. ¿Sera que le estoy errando al hacerlo con elementos de lista?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.container-orders {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.container-orders ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container-orders ul li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
}

.container-orders .order-images {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container-orders">
  
<ul>
  <li class="list">
    <img src="./images-experiment/planta-1.jpg" alt="planta" class="order-images">
    <p> planta 1 </p>
    <p class="price"> $ price </p>
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <img src="./images-experiment/planta-2.jpg" alt="planta" class="order-images">
    <p> planta 2 </p>
    <p class="price"> $ price </p>
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <img src="./images-experiment/planta-3.jpg" alt="planta" class="order-images">
    <p> planta 3 </p>
    <p class="price"> $ price </p>
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <img src="./images-experiment/planta-4.jpg" alt="planta" class="order-images">
    <p> planta 4 </p>
    <p class="price"> $ price </p>
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <img src="./images-experiment/planta-5.jpg" alt="planta" class="order-images">
    <p> planta 5 </p>
    <p class="price"> $ price </p>
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <img src="./images-experiment/planta-6.jpg" alt="planta" class="order-images">
    <p> planta 6 </p>
    <p class="price"> $ price </p>
  </li>
</ul>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Deberías poder hacerlo con space-between. Asegúrate de ponerlo en el padre y que tenga un tamaño definido y `display: flex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo podes hacer de la siguiente manera, cada *'list'* (flex) tiene dos elementos, un contenedor *'contenedor-img_name'* tambien flex con la foto y el nombre del producto, y otro que es el `<p>` del precio, ese *'list'* tendra `justify-content: space between` para que el precio quede sobre la derecha y el contenedor *img_name* a la izquierda, después solo debo dar formato a este último con `inline-flex` y `align-items: center` para que la foto y el precio estén en el centro del cross-axis.

```css
.container-orders {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.container-orders ul {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}

.container-orders ul li{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;
   margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
}

.container-orders .order-images {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border-radius: 8px;
}

.container-img_name{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.name{
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container-orders">
    <ul>
      <li class="list">
        <div class="container-img_name">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="planta" class="order-images">
          <p class="name"> planta 1 </p>
        </div>
        <p class="price"> $ price </p>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <div class="container-img_name">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="planta" class="order-images">
          <p class="name"> planta 2 </p>
        </div>
        <p class="price"> $ price </p>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <div class="container-img_name">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="planta" class="order-images">
          <p class="name"> planta 3 </p>
        </div>
        <p class="price"> $ price </p>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <div class="container-img_name">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="planta" class="order-images">
          <p class="name"> planta 4 </p>
        </div>
        <p class="price"> $ price </p>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <div class="container-img_name">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="planta" class="order-images">
          <p class="name"> planta 5 </p>
        </div>
        <p class="price"> $ price </p>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <div class="container-img_name">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="planta" class="order-images">
          <p class="name"> planta 6 </p>
        </div>
        <p class="price"> $ price </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
```

Tome una imagen de internet para que se vea.